# Why these lists don't work? (spring - mvc)

Tags: java, spring, list, spring-mvc, dynamic

i've been asked to learn java and spring mvc for work but seems i'm not really good at it :(
Anyway i'm trying to create two lists dynamically the first one works, the second doesn't (i didn't really understand the get and post methods i fear) can you tell me why?

```
@Controller
```

@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class ConfigController {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String saveNum(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("configuration", new Config());
    return "home";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "home", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveNumPost(@ModelAttribute(value = "configuration") Config config, Model model) {
    List<Driver> drivers = new ArrayList<Driver>();
    for (int i = 0; i < config.getDriversNum(); i++) {
        drivers.add(new Driver());
    }
    Championship championship = new Championship();
    championship.setDrivers(drivers);
    model.addAttribute("championship", championship);
    return "configDrivers";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "configDrivers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String saveDriverList() {
    return "configDrivers";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "configDrivers", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createCars(@ModelAttribute Championship championship, Config config, Model model) {
    List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
    for (int i = 0; i < championship.getDrivers().size(); i++) {
        cars.add(new Car());
    }
    championship.setCars(cars);
    model.addAttribute("championship", championship);

    return "configCars";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "configCars", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String saveTrackNum(@ModelAttribute Config config, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("configuration", config);
    return "trackNum";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "trackNum", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveTracks(@ModelAttribute(value = "configuration") Config config, Championship championship,
        Model model) {
    List<Track> tracks = new ArrayList<Track>();
    for (int i = 0; i < config.getTracksNum(); i++) {
        tracks.add(new Track());
    }
    championship.setTracks(tracks);
    model.addAttribute("championship", championship);

    return "configTracks";
}
```

}

home view

```
    <c:url var="url" value="/home"/>
    <form:form action="${url}" method="POST" modelAttribute="configuration">
        <label>Insert number of drivers:</label> <br> 
        <form:input path="driversNum" placeholder="Type drivers number"/>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" />
        <!--number races-->
    </form:form>
```

configDrivers view

```
  <c:url var="url" value="/configDrivers"/>

    <form:form action="${url}" method="POST" modelAttribute="championship">

        <label>Insert drivers:</label> 

        <c:forEach items="${championship.drivers}" var="driver" varStatus="i">
            <h3>Insert driver's name and surname of driver ${i.index} </h3>
            <form:input path="drivers[${i.index}].name" value="${driver.name}" placeholder="Type name here" />
            <br>
            <form:input path="drivers[${i.index}].surname" value="${driver.surname}" placeholder="Type surname here" />
            <br>
        </c:forEach>    
            <input type="submit" />
            <!--number races-->
    </form:form>
```

configCars view

```
    <c:url var="url" value="/configCars"/>

    <form:form action="${url}" method="POST" modelAttribute="championship">

        <label>Insert cars:</label> 

        <c:forEach items="${championship.cars}" var="car" varStatus="i">
            <h3>Insert driver's team ${i.index} </h3>
            <form:input path="cars[${i.index}].team" value="${car.team}" placeholder="Type team here" />
            <br>
        </c:forEach>    



            <input type="submit" />
            <!--number races-->
    </form:form>

    <select>
          <c:forEach items="${championship.drivers}" var="car" varStatus="i">
              <option value="${i.index}">${driver.name}</option>
          </c:forEach>
        </select>
```

the Car class

```
public class Car {

private String team;
private Driver driver;

public String getTeam() {
    return team;
}

public void setTeam(String team) {
    this.team = team;
}

public Driver getDriver() {
    return driver;
}

public void setDriver(Driver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}
```

}

an the championship class (the one with the lists)

```
public class Championship {

private List<Driver> drivers;
private List<Car> cars;
private List<Track> tracks;

public List<Driver> getDrivers() {
    return drivers;
}

public void setDrivers(List<Driver> drivers) {
    this.drivers = drivers;
}

public List<Car> getCars() {
    return cars;
}

public void setCars(List<Car> cars) {
    this.cars = cars;
}

public List<Track> getTracks() {
    return tracks;
}

public void setTracks(List<Track> tracks) {
    this.tracks = tracks;
}
```

}

Comment: yould you define `doesn´t work`.

Comment: Can you paste your error log.

Comment: The first one (drivers) works, when i give the number in home the controller creates a list of the value i gave it earlier, and i can fill the list with the form in configDrivers, the second one (cars) doesn't get created i fear. In fact in the view configCars doesn't appear the form

Comment: @professionallyme86 I don't have an error log, ii just doesn't create the list.  these are the views  http://imgur.com/a/g5glb

Comment: You are receiving drivers form correctly but not the cars page.Right ? Can you show the cars page once ?

Comment: `${driver.name}` to `${car.name}`?

Comment: @professionallyme86 i added the car class and the championship class to the post

Comment: @10086 i want the drivers names to be displayed in the select

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste this code :

```
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>(); 
      for (int i= 0; i < config.getDriversNum(); i++) { 
          cars.add(new Car()); 
      }
  Championship championship = new Championship();
  championship.setCars(cars); 
  model.addAttribute("championship",championship);
```

inside the printDrivers() method and check.

I think that should do the trick.

Comment: What is the view of configCar page when it comes up on the browser ?

Comment: you mean if i just paste "http://localhost:8080/formula1/configCars" in the address bar? It gives me the same view of the pic i posted earlier, but the select is empty (without the options fields)

Comment: Hi, at last yesterday i finally resolved the problem with you advice, but now i got another one :( i'm trying to do the same thing i did before but with the class track, the method works fine in get, but everytime i try to run the programma from the beginning (home) after i fill the teams form it gives the error "http error 405 request method post not supported" now i will edit the controller with the new one, can you help?